# Is it appropriate to ask about efficiency of a 3rd party tool

Tags: discussion

I want to know about some charting tools, and I want to know know the efficiency of a particular tool on a large data set. Is this an appropriate question?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for people to give you a review of a particular tool, yes? Well no, that sort of thing isn't really suitable for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't imagine any phrasing of that question which would be appropriate for Stack Overflow. That really seems to be a task you should perform and evaluate yourself. Even more so if it ultimately boils down to a recommendation question.

Perhaps there is a topic-related chat room however. Maybe you can ask for experiences in there. Or it might be a topic fit for a site like http://slant.co